# How to prevent cleaner from hanging my lock screen in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, lock-screen

In my workplace I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with unity, standard installation. When I leave my office I lock my screen (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>). During the evening, the office is cleaned. A few times, I've got back to work in the morning and my headphones are on my keyboard. My lock screen is hung, I can't clear password field, can't type anything, and can't use any other controls on lock screen (reboot, turn off button etc.). The mouse is working but clicking does nothing. Probably this is because the password field took huge input overnight and broke everything else. The cleaner "hacked" my computer :)

How can I prevent this? Can I somehow limit how many characters can be passed to the password input? Can I block the lock screen until I use some key combination to enable password input? Something similar to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> in Windows before I can input password to lock screen?

//EDIT
As @bytecommander wrote there was a bug for this and it is supposed to be fixed but somehow this does not work on my machine [Cat causes login screen to hang](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615)

```
$ apt policy unity-greeter                                                                                                                                            
unity-greeter:
  Installed: 16.04.2-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 16.04.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 16.04.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

// EDIT 2

Someone wrote that lock screen is not unity greeter package. Anyone can confirm this and tell me what package is this?

// EDIT 3

OK so it seems that lock screen is part of Unity and not greeter package. I filled a bug report for this: [Lock screen frozen after big input from keyboard](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1818354)

Comment: Power it down, take it home with you, unplug the keyboard if it's not a laptop, tell hr, AFAIR there's not much you can do security wise once someone physically gets a hold of your machine

Comment: @j-money I don't think the lady attempts to _hack_ the machine but rather think she just thoroughly _cleans_ the keyboard thereby pressing all the keys. A [dust cover](https://www.banggood.com/Acrylic-Keyboard-Protector-Dust-Cover-for-87-Mechanical-Keyboard-p-87811.html?cur_warehouse=CN) and/or [this note](https://floodandfiresolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/do-not-clean.jpg) might help.

Comment: @PerlDuck maybe that's what she wants you to think!! (couldn't resist)

Comment: Unplug the keyboard :)

Comment: @Sauce It requires additional actions from me every day, so no... :)

Comment: @Sauce also, risk of forgetting the keyboard is unplugged, then wondering why the keyboard is not working, spending long time until figuring out what's going on. ;)

Comment: Why not just put the headphones in a drawer before going home? Or hang them over the monitor?

Comment: Have you tried just pressing _Enter_? Perhaps that'll get the lock screen to try and validate your password, and fail, allowing things to work again...

Comment: @marcelm I tried pressing many keys, enter, escape, ctr+alt+del etc., nothing works. Lock screen is frozen.

Comment: @Mawg I don't have drawer at work. Monitors are also cleaned so headphones will be taken down and put on desk (on keyboard?). Also I don't think it is correct solution. This should be dealt with by limiting how much input can password field take.

Comment: Agreed. If you get such asolution. Failing that, a dollar store sucktion cup & hook would do, perhaps inside the well of hte desk

Answer (score 30):

Seems like your cleaner has successfully managed to emulate a cat.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1538615

There was a bug in `unity-greeter` in 14.04 and up to 16.04, which caused the lock screen to become unresponsive when there has been excessive keyboard input for some time (figuratively and literally a "cat on the keyboard").

It should be fixed since `unity-greeter` version `16.04.2-0ubuntu1` though by implementing a character limit. Please check your installed version with

```
apt policy unity-greeter
```

and make sure your system is fully updated with

```
sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I have version with fix: `apt policy unity-greeter
unity-greeter:
  Installed: 16.04.2-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 16.04.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 16.04.2-0ubuntu1 500` and apparently it is not fixed...

Comment: In that case I think you should (re)open a bug ticket :(

Comment: @ByteCommander I wrote comment in this ticket but I can't find option to reopen it :/

Comment: The lock screen in Unity is not the Unity Greeter, so any fix to the Unity Greeter package is not going to fix a problem in the Unity lock screen.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb so what is unity lock screen then? What package?

Comment: The lockscreen in Unity is built in to Unity.  The package name is "unity".  It's a plugin to compiz -- the running binary show up as 'compiz' in ps.  It's done this way to preven alt-F1 security exploits.

Comment: The out-of-the-box solution is to ditch headphones and switch to earphones.

Comment: "Seems like your cleaner has successfully managed to emulate a cat."  Just be glad it's not Dexter Douglas's cat! ;-)

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Ok thank you for this information. I read that Unity is abandoned but I've created a bug report anyway https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1818354

Answer (score 11):

You can **install xtrlock**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xtrlock
```

And made a combination for lock screen and lock keyboard, until you press the combination again. Make it hard and then the cleaner have a hard chance to hit and "hack" your computer.

Comment: This looks like the answer (short of removing the headphones, of course)

Comment: @Santi Will this automatically work when I lock my screen using ctrl+alt+l? I read a little about it and it seem to work same way as lock screen you type password and [enter] to unlock. Is it  protected from headphones on keyboard or cats? :)

Comment: @piotrekkr yep absolutely it works the same way, just bind both together, tell me how it's going

Comment: @Santi Ok. I'm wondering how should I combine them? If I use lock screen first then I'm locked and normal shortcut keys does not work. If I use only `xtrlock` then I have locked keyboard and can't lock screen normally (ctrl+alt+l). Did you mean to use only `xtrlock`?

Comment: @piotrekkr Yes, using only xtrlock you can set a custom shortcut to execute both, I mean, the lockscreen and lock keyboard until you press again the combination. This is an example of how it works [example of lock mouse and keyboard but not screen](https://www.ostechnix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/set-shortcut-key-3.png)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to buy a wireless keyboard, then stash the keyboard in a drawer before leaving, or taking out the USB dongle.

Pros: no need to install any software or mess with settings.
Cons: cost a bit of money, requires extra action before leaving.

Comment: Or a wired keyboard that you can just unplug at night.  Plenty of decent keyboards have a USB jack at both ends so you can unplug the cable at the keyboard (rather than having to fish behind the back panel connectors).

Comment: @J... oh, never seen a keyboard with USB jack on both ends, but yeah, guess in some places it might be available. Still, that would leave an orphan cord lying around at night. ;)

Comment: Well... sitting right next to the keyboard it should plug back into.  A reasonable cable management strategy should make sure the plug can't move far from where it should be in use.

Comment: @J... agreed, can be a better option indeed.

Comment: @J...: And many machines (I'm tempted to say any decent one these days) have USB jacks on the front, and in the monitor(s).  But unless there's an actual need for remote access during the night, the sensible course is simply to to turn the machine off when you leave.

Comment: @james I never turn off the machine at work because it takes 15 minutes to start, which is waste of time. Plus, cleaning lady might as well clean the power button and turn the computer on anyway. ;)

Comment: As an alternative, you can get a plain-jane KVM switch for pretty cheap; just switch channels when you leave. Benefit there is you won't be adding wear and tear to your USB port/plug, just press a button.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: If it takes 15 minutes to boot your computer, you have something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Think inside the box! ;)

Just fabricate a cardboard (or use a more durable material) box that encloses your keyboard (and mouse, if necessary) and put the keyboard in it when you leave. The cords, if any, can pass through open slots in the side of the box to make it easy to use without disconnecting anything.

It's pretty unlikely that the cleaner will deliberately open the box to clean the keyboard. You could add a simple lock if necessary. Just make it in such a way that your employer can get to the keyboard if necessary when you're not there. Using cardboard might help with that.